# How to get all child of a given id in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server database:

```
category( 
   itemid, 
   parentid
)

ArticleAssignedCategories(
   categid, 
   artid
)
```

`categid` is a foreign key of `itemid`

I want to get count of `artids` and child of that for given `itemid` (child means categories with `parentid` of given `itemid`.)

For example; If given `itemid = 1` and in table `category` have (3,1),(4,1)(5,3)

All of 3, 4, 5 are child of 1

Can anyone help me to write a good query?

Comment: You can use a recursive CTE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858567/how-to-get-all-children-and-itself-from-hierarchical-data-with-cte-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive queries can be done using CTE

```
with CTE(itemid, parentid)
as (
  -- start with some category
  select itemid, parentid
  from category where itemid = <some_itemid>
union all 
  -- recursively add children
  select c.itemid, c.parentid
  from category c 
  join CTE on c.parentid = CTE.itemid
)
select count(*)
from ArticleAssignedCategories a
join CTE on CTE.itemid = a.categid
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query. I hope this may help you

```
select b.artid,count(b.artid) from category a
inner join ArticleAssignedCategories b on a.itemid = b.artid
group by b.artid
```